# How do I turn PHP string into slug in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, slug

I have a page in wordpress I am using with a slug called `Bad-Debt-Recovery-in/`. I am using a custom php query on that page with strings in the URL's like this

```
Bad-Debt-Recovery-in/?zipcode=55555&location=Chambers%20County+AL
```

How can I make this url into a slug like this

```
Bad-Debt-Recovery-in/55555/Chambers-County/AL/
```

as a rewrite? Any help would be appreciated!

UPDATE: 
This code is actually what I am using. I also made it simpler and created a third variable named "state". One rewrite is for City and one is for County page:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^Bad-Debt-Recovery-And-Collection-Agencies-Services-In\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/? Bad-Debt-Recovery-And-Collection-Agencies-Services-In/?zipcode=$1&city=$2&state=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^Bad-Debt-Recovery-And-Collection-Agency-Services-In\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/? Bad-Debt-Recovery-And-Collection-Agency-Services-In/?countyid=$1&county=$2&state=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: add your code please

Comment: I added my code based on "Scriptonomy" explanation. It is still not working though. I may be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for, and seeking to accomplish is called: Converting a request path into a query string.

Use .htaccess RewriteRule directive to modify the incoming request

```
RewriteRule ^Bad-Debt-Recovery-in\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/? Bad-Debt-Recovery-in/?a=$1&b=$2&c=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Each `([^\/]+)` captures path elements into a variables `$1,$2,$3...`

The `?` at the end simply denotes that the last `/` is optional or else the last match could fail

the `\` simply escape the '/' for literal interpretation

Add as many `([^\/]+)` as needed and capture them in the query

```
zipcode=$1&location=$2+$3
```

The modifiers at the end `[QSA,L,NC]` are called flags

- QSA appends the query string to the end of the rewrite if any exist
- L simply says this is the last rewrite
- NC means not case sensitive

This is your final solution:

```
RewriteRule ^Bad-Debt-Recovery-in\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/? Bad-Debt-Recovery-in/?zipcode=$1&location=$2+$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try this and I will let you know if it is working for me.

Comment: I added the htaccess solution but it still isn't working. Do I make the links appear like this Bad-Debt-Recovery-in/?zipcode=55555&location=Chambers%20County+AL or the slug way? In other works, Does it change that url to the proper one? or do I have to type in the proper one? Should I flush my rules?

Comment: In addition, I added the rewrite rule just after these two lines: RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WP [function `sanitize_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title)

Combine this with a php loop i.e.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
foreach($_GET as $g){
  $url .= '/'.$g;
}
$url = sanitize_title($url);
```

Comment: How can this work? I am using the $_GET['zipcode'] on my query page but where would I put the function code?

Comment: @PhilM updated my answer with an example. SHould do the trick.

Comment: So I should put this within my php code that generates the urls? Or the next page that runs the queries?

Comment: on which ever page is receiving the get request